# Descriptive Statistics Gem Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statistics

I am trying to use descriptive statistics gem in rails on scores entered by the user. However, it keeps giving me this error.

uninitialized constant ScoresController::DescriptiveStatistics

scores_controller.rb

```
    def index                                      
          @statsD = User.all.extend(DescriptiveStatistics)
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Simple Stats:</h1>
                        <%= @statsD %>
```

I am new to rails so I'm struggling with the github directions for rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your app after the gem installation ?